# Can I add a Google Hangouts call to a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-hangouts

I was wondering if it is possible to create a script in Google Sheets to launch a Google Hangout that calls me, preferably by phone but it could also run a video call to my Google+ account.

I currently know how to create a drawing, create a basic function, and assign the script to the drawing to make a button. Just wondering if there is a script out there for this or if it would be possible.

Essentially, I'm trying to add a *"Call tech support"* button to a complicated spreadsheet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is some information here: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I was able to do was create a button that opens a dialog that shows a "Start a Hangout" button. You can then click that button to open a Hangout window. There may be a way to embed a Hangout window into the dialog directly, but from what I've read, there are restrictions on spreadsheets that prevent some javascript functionality. Here is the code I used:

Code.gs:

```
function HangoutButton() {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('HangoutButton').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Loading Hangout Button ...');
}
```

HangoutButton.html:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-hangout" data-render="createhangout"></div>
```

Here is a link to my [working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gar2wCZ3zRvYiXj8GaO_w6Nf2SwHGQaP8XfudXsdi4Y/edit?usp=sharing) (it may ask for you to give it permission). It has a button that I have linked to run the `HangoutButton()` method provided above.

Comment: Hey Chase,

It worked great! One quick question: is there a way where it automatically calls my Google Account or connects to a specific phone number?

Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: Hey Chase,

I was able to get the phone number and video chat to work by using the following HTML code:

``<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <g:hangout render="createhangout"
        invites="[{ id : '5558675309', invite_type : 'PHONE' }]">
    </g:hangout>
    <g:hangout render="createhangout"
        invites="[{ id : 'myemail@gmail.com', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]">
    </g:hangout>``

This creates 2 buttons: one for a phone call and the other for a video chat using the HTML code above. Thanks!

Comment: @SpecialKCa Sweet! Glad you were able to get it to work. Thanks for sharing your code. Cool idea.